# How to make sure that mvn verify fails when a plugin failed

Tags: java, maven

I want to run some (non-maven) integration tests in a docker container and therefore configured `io.fabric8.docker-maven-plugin` in my maven `pom.xml`. I added an `<execution>` for `<phase>integration-test</phase>` and it works. It runs all the tests I want.

The only thing that is missing now is that `verify` ends with `SUCCESS` even if the tests inside the docker container failed.

Is there a way to tell maven that if the command inside the docker container (which I started using the plugin) fails that the `verify` goal should also fail then?

Comment: How are you running the given tests you haven mentioned?

Comment: In my specific case I use `pyresttest`. This script runs inside the docker container.

Comment: Ah running inside the container...where do you start the tests? which is the point where to check for return code and fail the build in cases where the tests fail...